# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad stream type -100

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, soundpool

I am using `SoundPool` in my android application.
Passing following parameters in `SoundPool`.

```
spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

Sometimes it is giving this exception in android Rooted devices while adjusting volume.

Here is class which i'm using to play sound. I am calling `getInstance()` method while initializing Music_Manager class' instance and using methods inside this class by that instance.

```
public class Music_Manager {

    private SoundPool spool;
    Context mcontext;
    int s1, s2, s3;

    static Music_Manager instance;

    public static Music_Manager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Music_Manager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    Music_Manager() {
        try {


            spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

            s1 = spool.load(mcontext, R.raw.s1, 1);
            s2 = spool.load(mcontext, R.raw.s2, 1);
            s3 = spool.load(mcontext, R.raw.s3, 1);
        }catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }


    public void playS1() {
        try {
            spool.play(s1, 100, 100, 1, 0, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public void playS2() {
        try {
            spool.play(s2, 100, 100, 1, 0, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public void playS3() {
        try {
            spool.play(s3, 100, 100, 1, 0, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }


    public void release() {

        try
        {
            if (spool != null)
                spool.release();
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Exception :**

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad stream type
>   -100
>          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1469)
>          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
>          at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(IAudioService.java:936)
>          at android.media.AudioManager.adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(AudioManager.java:658)
>          at android.media.AudioManager.handleKeyDown(AudioManager.java:527)
>          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDown(PhoneWindow.java:1563)
>          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1969)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
>          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>          at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
>          at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
>          at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Comment: Please post the detailed code for the same.

Comment: @xCodeZone I have added that class here...

Comment: I am getting the same crash, @MayankPandya were you able to resolve this?